# Eclipse displays png as a text file

Tags: 13.10, android, eclipse, png

I want to create an app in eclipse with libGDX. But when I import a png file into Eclipse it displays it as a text file. I tried with the Android Developmet Kit from Google, but the same problem as well.

I think this is an Ubuntu specific problem, because previously I worked on a Windows XP computer with eclipse, and there wasn't this problem.

I have Eclipse Kepler on Ubuntu 13.10.
[image: The png file in eclipse]

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: What external editor did you use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need to tell Eclipse which editor to use. Go to `Preferences > General > Editors > File Associations`. Create an entry for `*.png` if necessary and then Add an Associated editor specifying the External program you want to use.